# Checking Tuples in a list

Tags: python, mysql, login-script

So i am working on a program that is  and I am stuck.
I have a login and signup system that saves new signups in a mysql database.
At the start of the program I take the passwords and names and put them together in a tuple.
Then i put that tuple in a list.
If i wanna login it cant check a tuple in that list.
Here is my code:
Login:

```
def login():
    userKnown = input("Hallo, heeft u al een account? y/n ")

    if userKnown == "y":
        user = input("username: ")
        passw = input("password: ")
        userjoin = (user,passw)
        if userjoin in bigdata:
            print("login succesful")
        else:
            print("try again")
```

UploadData:

```
def uploadData():
    print("Bezig met uploaden.")
    mycursor.execute("SELECT name, password FROM userData")
    data = mycursor.fetchall()
    bigdata.append(data)
    print("Upload worked. \n")
```

I hope someone can help me.

A fix to the login system.

Comment: Do you really want to read the entire user table to check if a record exists? SELECT has a WHERE clause where you can specify conditions.

Comment: What is ```bigdata``` you haven't declared it in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it thanks to Georg Richter.

I used the Where function in select and that worked

Here is the code:

```
def login():
    userKnown = input("Hallo, heeft u al een account? y/n ")

    if userKnown == "y":
        user = input("username: ")
        passw = input("password: ")
        userB = (user, passw)
        query = 'SELECT name, password FROM userData WHERE name =%s'
        name = (user,)
        mycursor.execute(query, name)
        userA = mycursor.fetchone()
        print(userA)
        if userA == userB:
            print("succes")
        else:
            print("failed")
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the error is that bigdata does not exist into your `login` function.
Try this: `def login(bigdata)` and call the function in this way: `login(bigdata)`

Comment: This is not working

Comment: Can you give me more info? What's your problem? Do you receive an error? Does it only return "try again"?
I tried your function login modified as I said and it works. Are you sure that data you give to bigdata is correct?
Try to catch error and be sure of what your variable have stored.
Also notice that you have the same problem in your `uploadData()` function. You should pass bigdata and return it.
If bigdata is an instance variable, you could declare it in the class and use `self.bigdata` instead

Answer (score -1):

Try using try block to find the user its easier this way.

```
try:
    pass
    #code to search database
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

SELECT has a WHERE clause where you can specify user and password to optimize your application.

Comment: either you don't know how to up vote or appreciate support. Try to ask your questions properly

Comment: I actually can’t vote yet so. And u were after the other person that answered my question.